# Google Spreadsheet Query - combine three lists of results

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I have 3 lists of items in a spreadsheet and all I waant to make one big list out of them. Could anyone please help?

```
List1:
a1

a2

List2: 
b1

b2
b3

List3:
c1

c2
```

THE RESULT (in my dreams:) - ONE BIG LIST without empty rows:

```
a1
a2
b1
b2
b3
c1
c2
```

My approach:

I tried sth like

```
= QUERY(A2:A; "select A where A !=''")&QUERY(B2:B; "select B where B !=''")=&QUERY(C2:C; "select C where C !=''")
```

But this does not work :(

Screen: http://prntscr.com/5acav3

[image: a]

The spreadsheet (public to edit) [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vC5P1rq9E6usJe5lNmOU-RfrNdyIQ7pXkXGeY3YLWps/edit#gid=0)

The problem is similar to the one in SQL [Select values from multiple columns into single column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19515829/select-values-from-multiple-columns-into-single-column) but there are different commands and it is not working...

Best regards
Marcin

Answer (score 3):

In the sheet you shared I entered in H2:

```
=query({A2:A;B2:B;C2:C}; "Select * where Col1 <>'' ")
```

and in I2:

```
=ArrayFormula(transpose(split(concatenate(A2:C&"/");"/")))
```

Both formulas should output the same BIG list ... ;-)